# Array indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way in numpy to retrieve all items in an array except the item of the index provided.

```
 x = 
 array([[[4, 2, 3],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [1, 3, 4]],

   [[2, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 3],
    [3, 4, 2]],

   [[2, 4, 1],
    [0, 2, 2],
    [4, 0, 0]]])
```

and by asking for

```
x[not 1,:,:]
```

you will get

```
array([[[4, 2, 3],
    [2, 0, 1],
    [1, 3, 4]],

   [[2, 4, 1],
    [0, 2, 2],
    [4, 0, 0]]])
```

Thanks

Comment: For your simple example, you can use `x[::2,:,:]`

Comment: so what if x = np.random.ranint(10,size=(1000,3,3)) and I am trying to get a view of the matrix without the ith 3X3 matrix. Your approach cant be generalized :)

Comment: For the general case, I think indexing with a tuple would be easiest.. although maybe there is some numpy magic that I'm not aware of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In [42]: x[np.arange(x.shape[0])!=1,:,:]
Out[42]: 
array([[[4, 2, 3],
        [2, 0, 1],
        [1, 3, 4]],

       [[2, 4, 1],
        [0, 2, 2],
        [4, 0, 0]]])
```

Comment: +1 This is just beautiful! With `x[np.arange(x.shape[0])!=1,:,:]` it would be even perfect :-)

Comment: Thanks for the improvement, eurimo.

Comment: I knew unutbu would chime in with a nice answer :)  even `x[np.arange(x.shape[0]) != 1]` will work, the other dims will take `:` by default

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
a[(0,2), :, :]
```

Instead of blacklisting what you don't want to get, you can try to whitelist what you need.

If you need to blacklist anyway, you can do something like this:

```
a[[i for i in range(a.shape[0]) if i != 1], :, :]
```

Basically you just create a list with all possible indexes (`range(a.shape[0])`) and filter out those that you don't want to get displayed (`if i != 1`).

Comment: What if I have 1000 2D matrices ?? should it be (0,2,3,4,...).

Comment: @JustInTime I'm not sure I understand, but the `[i for i in range(a.shape[0]) if i != 1]` expression will let you create a mask for all the indexes you need except `1` regardless of number of matrices because of `a.shape[0]` usage.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a generic solution:

```
x[range(0,i)+range(i+1,x.shape[0]),:,:]
```